# How to timeout asyncio.to_thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I experimenting with the [new asyncio features](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines-and-tasks) in Python 3.9, and have the following code:

```
import asyncio

async def inc(start):
    i = start
    while True:
        print(i)
        i += 2
    return None

async def main():
    x = asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(inc, 0),
        asyncio.to_thread(inc, 1)
    )
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(x, timeout=5.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("timeout!")

asyncio.run(main())
```

My expectation is that the program will print numbers starting from `0` and terminate after 5 seconds. However, when I execute the program [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/python3-programming-online/), I see no output and the following warning:

```
/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py:80: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'inc' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py:85: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'inc' was never awaited
  del work_item
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [asyncio.to_thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) converts a *regular* function to a coroutine.

All you need is to change the `async def inc` to `def inc`. You can do this, because there is no `await`, it is not a real coroutine.

However, you cannot kill a thread. The timeout will cause to stop waiting, not to stop computing numbers.

UPDATE: In detail, the `asyncio.gather` awaits the coroutines until the timeout. When cancelled by the timeout, the `gather` cancels all still running coroutines a and waits for their termination. Cancelling a coroutine means to deliver an exception at the nearest `await` statement. In this case, there is no `await` and the coroutines will never receive the cancellation exception. The program hangs at that point.

Comment: I only seem to be getting the output from the even thread, and not seeing the timeout statement from the main thread or the odd numbers. Have you ran it yourself?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I added an UPDATE about not reaching the print('timeout')

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar In my output there are both even and odd numbers, but they are in blocks of several thousands numbers of same kind (odd/even).

Comment: Good explanation, thanks.